# Bound Oracle Text "near" operator to the same sentences

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I have a column that stores paragraphs with multiple sentences and I am using the "Near" statement to look for the right record. However, is it possible to bound the near statement that only look for words within the same sentences.

For example:

## **Paragraph**

> "An elderly man has died as a result of ***coronavirus*** in the Royal
>   Hobart Hospital overnight. It follows the ***death*** of a woman in her 80s
>   in the North West Regional Hospital in Burnie on Monday morning, and
>   brings the national toll to 19. "

indextype is **ctxsys.context**

select
score(1)
from
tbl
where
contains(Paragraph,
'Near (coronavirus, death),20,false)',1) > 0

The result I want is **nothing** as both words is from a different sentences. However, now it will return me a positive number as both words are less than 20 words apart.

Can you share me some idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
select score(1) 
from   tbl
where  contains(Paragraph, 'Near (coronavirus, death),20,false) 
                            WITHIN SENTENCE',1) > 0
;
```

That is - use the `WITHIN` operator.

Note that you must tell the index to recognize sentences first. That is: if you created the index with a statement like this:

```
create index ctxidx on tbl(Paragraph)
indextype is ctxsys.context
-- parameters(' ... ')
;
```

where the `parameters` (if you used that clause) don't say anything about "sentences", you will get an error if you try the query above - something along the lines of

```
DRG-10837: section sentence does not exist
```

First you will have to define "special" sections for sentences:

```
begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_section_group('my_section_group', 'AUTO_SECTION_GROUP');
  ctx_ddl.add_special_section('my_section_group', 'SENTENCE');
end;
/
```

With this in hand:

```
drop index ctxidx;

create index ctxidx on tbl(Paragraph)
indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters ('section group my_section_group')
;
```

Now you are ready to successfully run the query at the top of this Answer.

Comment: Hi  Mathguy, Thanks for your help. However, I ran into ORA-06550 'CTX_DDL must be declared' when try to create the section group.  Have I missed anything?

Comment: @ELeung - The user who works with Oracle Text (perhaps that's you) must have been granted `execute` privilege on the `CTXSYS.CTX_DDL` package. If you have a DBA, talk to him or her. If you are your own DBA, read the Oracle Text documentation; this is one of the first things that must be done when creating an Oracle Text user (that is, a database user who is going to work with Oracle Text on a regular basis).

Comment: Thx Mathguy! I will check with my DBA. :)

Comment: @ELeung - point your DBA to the documentation (link below) - there are several packages on which he must grant you the `execute` privilege. (Make sure you find the same documentation, for your Oracle Database version; this is for version 12.1, which is what I use). https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-2654C316-2C70-4CD1-AFA4-5FD601D8624F.htm#CCAPP9014

Comment: Hi Mathguy, I am still waiting for my DBA to come back to me due to COVID 19. However, while waiting for this, I have used the old school silly style by replacing all full stops(.) with 50 dummy words. "   Z.  ". (Which will caused two sentences being apart by 50 words, would it cause any impact to the score? Thanks a lot!